# Export salesforce report as CSV

Tags: python, salesforce

I'm trying to pull salesforce reports through python. I've tried this approach:

```
import requests

l = requests.get('sfinstanceurl/?un=user&pw=passw')

report = requests.get('sfinstanceurl/reportid?view=d&snip&export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv',cookies=l.cookies)

print(report.content)
```

Also this one:

```
def sfdc_to_pd(reportid):

    login_data = {'un': 'your_username', 'pw': 'your_password'}

    with requests.session() as s:
    s.get('https://your_instance.salesforce.com', params = login_data)
    d = requests.get("https://your_instance.salesforce.com/{}?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv".format(reportid), headers=s.headers, cookies=s.cookies)
    lines = d.content.splitlines()
    reader = csv.reader(lines)
    data = list(reader)
    data = data[:-7]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df = df.drop(0)
    return df
    print df
```

And for both, when i print the content I get this (even though the status response is always 200):

```
b'\r\n<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">\n<html>\n<head>\n    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">\n\n\n\n\n\n<script>\nif (this.SfdcApp && this.SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator) { SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator.handleRedirect(\'sfinstanceurl?ec=302&startURL=%2F00O0m000000JzRc%3Fview%3Dd%26enc%3DUTF-8%26export%3D1%26xf%3Dcsv%26snip%3D\'); }  else \nif (window.location.replace){ \nwindow.location.replace(\'sfinstanceurl?ec=302&startURL=%2F00O0m000000JzRc%3Fview%3Dd%26enc%3DUTF-8%26export%3D1%26xf%3Dcsv%26snip%3D\');\n} else {;\nwindow.location.href =\'sfinstanceurl?ec=302&startURL=%2F00O0m000000JzRc%3Fview%3Dd%26enc%3DUTF-8%26export%3D1%26xf%3Dcsv%26snip%3D\';\n} \n</script>\n\n</head>\n\n\n</html>\n\n\n\n\n\n<!-- Body events -->\n<script type="text/javascript">function bodyOnLoad(){if(window.PreferenceBits){window.PreferenceBits.prototype.csrfToken="null";};}function bodyOnBeforeUnload(){}function bodyOnFocus(){}function bodyOnUnload(){}</script>\n\t\t\t\n</body>\n</html>\n\n\n<!--\n...................................................................................................\n...................................................................................................\n...................................................................................................\n...................................................................................................\n-->\n'
```

My company uses SSO, so security tokens are not something i have to try a different approach. Am I missing something? Why do I not get the report in the content?

**EDIT:**

I also just tried this approach:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import requests
import base64
import json

sf = Salesforce(username=    #login
                ,password=  # password
                ,security_token= # token )

print "get sid ", sf.session_id

response = requests.get("https://instancename/reportid?view=d&snip&export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv",
                  headers = sf.headers, cookies = {'sid' : sf.session_id})

response.content
```

It still returns the same HTML object.

Comment: Looks like you're getting a HTML object instead of the expected csv format. Try to use a salesforce python module like simple-salesforce to do the authentication and combining it with requests to access a specific report. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47414/download-a-report-using-python

Comment: @BoboDarph i just tried that (the simple_salesforce approach) and still get the same HTML response. Will update the question.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are running reports from the SF instance directly, this will always return HTML as it is not an API call.

To access Reports through an API please refer to the documentation for Salesforce Reports and Dashboards REST API:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_intro.htm

Below is a link to the resources specifically for reports:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_get_reportdata.htm

When using Simple Salesforce you can easily call the API, like this:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import requests
import base64
import json

sf = Salesforce(username=[username],password=[password],security_token=[token])
reportId = '00OR0000000K2UeMAK'
reportRESTPath = ('analytics/reports/{id}'.format(id='00OR0000000K2UeMAK')

# Synchronous report get

reportJSON = sf.restful(reportRESTPath, {'includeDetails': 'true'})

# Asynchronous report create

asyncJobJSON = sf.restful(reportRESTPath, {'includeDetails': 'true'}, 'POST')

# Asynchronous report get

reportJSON = sf.restful(('{basePath}/instances/{instanceId}'.format(basePath=reportRESTPath,instanceId=asyncJobJSON.Id), {'includeDetails': 'true'})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. After a couple of tweaks, I was able to get this approach to work, however, how would I add a filter in the synchronous request? I've read through several parts of the documentation and it seems it has to go in the body of the request. How do i do this?

Comment: @rodrigocf it does not look like Simple Salesforce has allowed the body to be amended. You can perhaps code this yourself? The details of the requests.session.request method can be found here http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/ that will be useful when extending. See param "data"