# Programmatically download Salesforce report as csv

Tags: python, csv, url, python-requests, salesforce

I am trying to download a salesforce report using python.

```
csv_url = 'https://xyz.salesforce.com/reportid?csv=1&exp=1&enc=UTF-8&isdtp=p1'

r = requests.get(csv_url)
url_content = r.content
csv_file = open('my_file.csv','wb')

csv_file.write(url_content)
csv_file.close()
```

The file gets downloaded but it is some HTML object rather than the actual file. We use SSO, do I have to try a different approach?

Comment: check https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47414/download-a-report-using-python

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443107/export-salesforce-report-as-csv