# Get text body from SalesForce report

Tags: python, python-requests, simple-salesforce

I am trying to get SalesForce report via python using requests library. I am able to login successfully. The output I get with python does not contain any text body. How can I extract the text from python output.

```py
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import requests
import pandas as pd

sf = Salesforce(username='', 
                password='',
                security_token='')



export_url = 'https://gkg-mfsa.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Report/00O9N000000JwK2UAK/?export=1&enc=UTF-8&cf=csv'

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(export_url, 
                       headers=sf.headers, 
                       cookies={'sid': sf.session_id})
download_report = response.content.decode('utf-8')
print(download_report)
```

output

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">





<script>
function redirectOnLoad() {
if (this.SfdcApp && this.SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator) { SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator.handleRedirect('https://gkg-mfsa.my.salesforce.com?ec=302&startURL=%2Fvisualforce%2Fsession%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fgkg-mfsa.lightning.force.com%252Flightning%252Fr%252FReport%252F00O9N000000JwK2UAK%252F%253Fexport%253D1%2526enc%253DUTF-8%2526cf%253Dcsv'); }  else 
if (window.location.replace){ 
window.location.replace('https://gkg-mfsa.my.salesforce.com?ec=302&startURL=%2Fvisualforce%2Fsession%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fgkg-mfsa.lightning.force.com%252Flightning%252Fr%252FReport%252F00O9N000000JwK2UAK%252F%253Fexport%253D1%2526enc%253DUTF-8%2526cf%253Dcsv');
} else {
window.location.href ='https://gkg-mfsa.my.salesforce.com?ec=302&startURL=%2Fvisualforce%2Fsession%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fgkg-mfsa.lightning.force.com%252Flightning%252Fr%252FReport%252F00O9N000000JwK2UAK%252F%253Fexport%253D1%2526enc%253DUTF-8%2526cf%253Dcsv';
} 
} 
redirectOnLoad();
</script>

</head>


</html>





<!-- Body events -->
<script type="text/javascript">function bodyOnLoad(){if(window.PreferenceBits){window.PreferenceBits.prototype.csrfToken="null";};}function bodyOnBeforeUnload(){}function bodyOnFocus(){}function bodyOnUnload(){}</script>
            
</body>
</html>


<!--
...................................................................................................
...................................................................................................
...................................................................................................
...................................................................................................
-->
```

How can I get the text part from the output?

Edit:

I have also tried simple_salesforce library approach, specifically using sf.restful to get the report. That gives me a invalid session id error, I have also posted a question about that, you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74900641/change-path-in-simple-salesforce-library)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export salesforce report as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443107/export-salesforce-report-as-csv)

Comment: Do the headers contain [`Accept: text/csv`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076042/what-mime-type-should-i-use-for-csv) to [request the desired format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-accept) ? Can use `print(sf.headers)` for debugging.
See also [related question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47414/download-a-report-using-python) or ask on [salesforce.se].

Comment: @hc_dev I have checked that approach out, it did not help in my case, edited the question with more information on what I have tried

Comment: @hc_dev print(sf.headers) returns {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': '', 'X-PrettyPrint': '1'}, I deleted the authorization part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "works for me" (org doesn't have "enhanced domains" enabled yet), put your report id

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import requests

sf = Salesforce(username='secret@example.com', 
                password='hunter2',
                security_token='')

print(sf.sf_instance)
print(sf.session_id)

export_url = export_url = 'https://' + sf.sf_instance + '/' + '00O5J000000y5LVUAY?isdtp=p1&export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv'

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(export_url, 
                       headers=sf.headers, 
                       cookies={'sid': sf.session_id})
download_report = response.content.decode('utf-8')
print(download_report)
```

Comment: This solution gives the same exact html output I added to the question

Comment: does it print a plausible-looking session id (00D... exclamation mark, some random garbage later) and instance url that has no sight of anything "lightning" in the url. Do you see successful login in your user's login history in setup. Did you have to provide security token? or maybe you added your IP to trusted range in Setup -> Network Access?

Comment: is it sandbox or production? The report url looks sandbox-ish... For sandboxes "simple" says to add `domain='test'` to your `Salesforce()` call. Did you login to prod but hope to pull report from sandbox?

Comment: I get the session id in correct format with sf.session_id. Instance url is "'gkg-mfsa.my.salesforce.com". My login attempts seem active in login history. I did provide a security token. Trying domain = "test" approach

Comment: I tried to set the domain as "test" but I got the error :SalesforceAuthenticationFailed: INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.

Comment: current domain is "login"

Comment: go to setup in the org where the report is and try to search for "sandboxes" in the sidebar. if there's such option - you're in production and it should all work with the code I posted. What do you get if you manually go to the report's "export url" in browser, does it instant download the CSV?
if you don't see "sandboxes" option in setup -> you are in a sandbox. need to adjust your login Salesforce() call, username probably with suffix and the domain = test (assuming you're allowed to login from test.salesforce.com, sometimes admins allow only custom Setup -> MyDomain)

Comment: If I go to reports export url in browser, it instantly downloads the csv. I cannot see the sidebar where my report is in salesforce. But I inspected the report page and searched for sandbox, one result is found. 0 results came up when I searched for production. Does this mean, if I am in sandbox, I am not able to see the report? Unfortunately I could not even create a connected app (because I did not have permissions) and asked from a salesforce admin to do it.

Comment: If your report is in sandbox you need `domain='test'` in the login call and correct username (most of the time they have sandbox suffix so "sara lastname at gkg com mfsa" or something like that). Go to the report org's Setup -> Company Information and look at org id (00D...). Compare it with beginning of session id you get back from successful login. Do they match?

Comment: I asked salesforce admin and turns out I wasn't in sandbox :/ Organization id checks with session id

Comment: I'm out of ideas then. This works with my production, with my developer edition (well, after changing the report id and credentials of course). You say login history entry looks good, manual navigation to URL insta downloads the CSV... Are you using same credentials for web and python login? Maybe something with permissions, really clutching at straws here

Comment: Turns out the issue was that I did not have admin privileges, the code you provided works fine, unless the privileges are missing